# how to make sure that web traffic originates ONLY via a specific URL?

Tags: apache, security, .htaccess, server-side

I have a site (A) that I would like to distribute to students.
I have some materials there that I do not want to make public, as the materials will serve as a future textbook that I would like to sell.

Is there any way to make sure that access is *only* granted if the user navigates to site (A) via another site (B)??

For example, site (A)

```
somesite.com/page_to_be_exposed.html
```

Will only be viewable if navigated to from site (B):

```
anothersite.com/somepage.html
```

I am open to *any* suggestions, but I figured a solution might have something to do with the tags I've posted here.  I'll add other tags if people find a need for other methods / languages.

Thanks for any suggestions, this is all very new to me.
jml

Comment: To be honest, I fear this will only "feign" security. Using any in an array of addons, I can spoof my referrer header and you will be none the wiser. Can't you set up some simple authentication?

Comment: I would, but we're talking about a lot of students here.  Do you have any links to a good tutorial on how to set this up?  Also, would you use PHP? Rails? Other?

Comment: wait i'll make this into an answer.

Comment: @JanWesterdiep it generally considered a bad practice to change the nature of the question once it has been asked and even more if it has been replied already. If you have an answer to solve a different issue, the OP (jml) should open a new question for it.

Comment: @JanWesterdiep I can make a new thread; I am _very_ interested in your info and help.  Apologies for not making this question more open; I will post the new URL within the hour.

Comment: @jml if my answer replied what you asked here please pick it as correct. It is not-nice to invest my time to lose it because of a misunderstanding.

Comment: @Alec: I appreciate your help, but please have some patience.  I mentioned to you before that I would check this out and post back.  This will take a bit of time.

Comment: @jml in case you find any problems comment on my answer again so I can help again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `.htaccess` file as you have found it can have to do with this.

Having `mod_rewrite` enabled a rule like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.com
RewriteRule - - [R=403,L]
```

In a `.htaccess` file located in the root of the directory you want to protect against hot-linking, should do the job.

However this will only avoid people from hot-linking, not from accesing your content. So if security is a concern. Take a look at Apache’s [`mod_auth_basic`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html)
.

Comment: Very cool.  Thanks for your info!  I will check this out and post back.

Comment: Note that it is possible to spoof the `HTTP_REFERER` header, so this isn't really a reliable solution.

Comment: I ended up using something more like `<Limit GET> order allow, deny allow from mysite.com deny from all </Limit>`  -- Unfortunately, this doesn't allow mysite.com to access the page.

Comment: @jml Did you try the example I gave?

Comment: yes.  it doesn't work for me. did you read my modified question?

Comment: although i still wasn't able to verify this, i am marking it as correct, because my original question was asked based on traffic originating _from_ a URL, _NOT_ traffic embedding the destination site in an iframe.  thanks for your help...  i ended up using standard authentication via htpasswd anyway.

Comment: Thanks for picking it, though, didn’t you try modifying the example with the appropriate URLs? Please show me what you ended up trying so I can help you make it work.

Comment: I ended up just password protecting the dir.  Safer.